# SpringRunner and BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD starts app additional time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

When I create a JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public final class MyIT {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ... do some tests...
    }

}
```

And run the test it causes the SpringBoot application to start 2 times, the second time will execute the test.
When I remove `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` it correctly starts application once.

How can I disable this first pointless start of Spring Boot app in tests?

Comment: Do you really need it on the class level? :)

Comment: I need each test to be run in isolated environment (not reusing one from other tests), so I think yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD might work for you

Comment: I was somehow thinking that would just inverted the order of those two startups, but nope, you are right. It works now, there are no unnecessary Spring Boot startups. Thanks

Comment: Yep, I ran into the same problem while trying to come up with a solution to manage Docker containers startup / shutdown when running Integration Tests (more at http://tech.asimio.net/2016/08/04/Integration-Testing-using-Spring-Boot-Postgres-and-Docker.html) and AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD did work.